# Cardinality of generated rings and generated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, modules, set-theory

I've once asked a similar question only about groups, but I am interested whether the logic is still sound:

$(1)$Let $S$ be a generating set of a ring $R$, and denote $\kappa=\vert S\vert$. Then $\vert R\vert \leq \kappa$, and if $\kappa<\aleph_0$ then $\vert R \vert \leq \aleph_0$.

This is because any element is written as a finite sum of finite products of elements in $S$. Thus if we denote:

$R_{n,m}:=\Big\{ \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}} \underset{j=1}{\overset{m_i}{\prod}} a_{i,j} \Big\vert m_i\leq m, \;  \{ a_{i,j} \}\subseteq S  \Big\}$

We can see that $R=\underset{n,m=1}{\overset{\infty}{\cup}}R_{n,m}$. Hence:

$\vert R\vert\leq \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\underset{m=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\vert R_{n,m}\vert$. Where if $\kappa\geq \aleph_0$ then $\vert R_{n,m}\vert=\kappa$, and if $\kappa<\aleph_0$ then $\vert R_{n,m\vert } \leq \aleph_0$.

$(2)$The natural follow up question (using similar logic) is for a Module $M$ over a ring $R$, if $S$ generates the module $M$ such that $\vert S\vert= \kappa\geq \aleph_0$  is it true that:

$\vert M \vert=\kappa$ if $\kappa \geq \vert R\vert$, and $\vert M\vert=\vert R\vert$ if $\vert R\vert>\kappa$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work under the assumption that both $|R|$ and $|S|$ are infinite. You can work out the other cases.

There is a surjective map from the set $\Sigma_{<\omega}(R\times S)$ of finite sequences from the set $R\times S$ onto the set $M$. By standard cardinality arguments,
$$
|\Sigma_{<\omega}(R\times S)|=|R\times S|
$$
so we can conclude that
$$
|S|\le|M|\le|R\times S|
$$

It is known that
$$
|R\times S|=\begin{cases}
|R| & \text{if $|R|>|S|$} \\[4px]
|S| & \text{if $|S|\ge|R|$}
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore, if $|R|\le|S|$ you can argue that $|M|=|S|$.

If $|S|<|R|$, one can have $|M|<|R|$. Let $R=J_p$ be the [ring of $p$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number); then $R/pR$ is finite (isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$) and we can consider the module $M=(R/pR)^{(\aleph_0)}$ (countable direct sum of copies of $R/pR$). Then we can take $S=M$ and $|S|=|M|=\aleph_0$, but $|R|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

What's the obstruction? There is no injective homomorphism (no injective map, actually) $R\to M$, in this case.

Comment: Would it be true then to say that $\vert M\vert \leq \vert R\vert$ always? or is this also not necessarily true?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur If $|S|>|R|$, then $|M|=|S|>|R|$ (infinite case).

Comment: I should have been more clear, the additional question I asked was if one adds the assumption that $\vert S\vert \leq \vert R\vert$.